# First point of entry on U.K visa

Tags: india, ireland, dublin

Hi I am an Indian with a short stay UK visa and I need to travel to Derry.

Can Dublin be my first point of entry or should it be a port in UK only?

Comment: What they are asking for is your first port of entry *into the UK*.

Comment: Is your visa endorsed BIVS? If not, you will need a separate visa for Ireland.

Comment: If *only transit* in Dublin, Indian Nationals are not required to be issued with Transit visas in order to get a connecting flight from an Irish Airport to another country. [link](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Transit%20Visas)

Answer (score 2):

If your visa has the BIVS endorsement, you can use your visa to enter Ireland but not as the first point of entry.

From the [Irish Naturalisation and Immigration Service FAQ](https://www.dfa.ie/media/embassyindia/ourservices/bivs-faq.pdf):

> You should apply for your visa from the country in which you will
>   arrive first. If you plan to travel to Ireland first, and then go the
>   UK, you should apply for an Irish visa. If you apply for a
>   multiple-entry visa, you should note that each time you travel you
>   must arrive first in the country which issued your visa.

AND

> If your visa has BIVS marked on it, it can be used to travel to both
>   Ireland and the UK. You must land first in the country which issued
>   your visa.

[image: Timatic Indian National / IRE / UK]

Comment: Apparently there is an exception for air transit, but I certainly do not understand how that would work in practice.

Comment: Thanks @phoog, I have attached Timatic. I don't know how an air transit or a transit would work for Ireland / Northern Ireland.

Comment: I would like to add a last paragraph but would like someone else to check the logic, "Also, I checked Timatic and attached the results here. I think the wording is a bit ambiguous and does not adequately describe the issue at hand, entering the Republic of Ireland to visit a United Kingdom destination on the island of Ireland. I don't think this qualifies as a transit unless he has an onward flight to Belfast and even then, he clearly is entering the Common Travel Area in the Republic of Ireland and thus will be inspected there and requires an appropriate Irish visa."

Comment: @RodneyHawkins I don't think there are any scheduled flights from Dublin to Belfast.